# nginx multisite reverproxy using path variable

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have multisite settings on single instance, I mean using site id, I'm switching content, logo theme colors etc and I have different domain names for each site.

Paths

```
http://localhost:3000/{{site_id}}/ 
http://localhost:3000/{{site_id}}/about-us/
http://localhost:3000/{{site_id}}/product/1232/slug

etc...
```

For Example

```
http://localhost:3000/1 => site-a.local
http://localhost:3000/2 => site-b.local
http://localhost:3000/3 => site-c.local
```

I'm using nginx, reverse proxy from port 80 to 3000. How can I forward the site id in the nginx

```
server {

   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   
   server_name site-a.local;


   location ~ /(.*) {
    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    
    }

}


server {

   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   
   server_name site-b.local;


   location ~ /(.*) {
    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/2;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     
    }

}
```

The above idea is not working for some reason can someone help me?

Comment: what is not working? Am i right you are trying to have multiple nginx server blocks with different Domains proxied to the same upstream `127.1:3000` but with different locations?

Comment: Yes correct, I have an application runs in 3000 port, It displays different content based first path variable /{site_id}, So I want nginx to route the different domains to different site_id, I don't what to show the site_id to the user, I want to mask like this `http://localhost:3000/1/ => site-a.local`

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream node {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  keepalive 32;
}



server {
  server_name site-a.local;
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://node/1/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}


server {
  server_name site-b.local;
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://node/2/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

  }
}


server {
  listen 3000;
  location /1/ { return 200 "Hello from 1 with URL $uri"; }
  location /2/ { return 200 "Hello from 2 with URL $uri"; }
}
```

With this you are proxying to your node backend, listening on port `3000`.

```sh
$:/etc/nginx/conf.d# curl -H "Host: site-a.local" 127.1/test/location/
Hello from a with URL /a/test/location/


$:/etc/nginx/conf.d# curl -H "Host: site-b.local" 127.1/test/location/
Hello from b with URL /b/test/location/
```

Comment: Sorry, I was out of station, I'm getting error like this  "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block

Comment: Sorry for my late reponse. In my configuration there are no regex locations. Do you need REGEX based locations? Plese check your configuration one more time and make sure there is no `~` in the location configuration.